# Error: React Module not found: Can't resolve '@atlaskit/util-data-test' when I update @atlaskit/util-data-test from 15.0.1 to 17.0.1

Tags: reactjs, emoji, versionupgrade

I am upgrading my @atlaskit/util-data-test' dependency to 17.0.1 from 15.0.1 and I am getting this error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@atlaskit/util-data-test' in '/Table/TextEditor'
```

Text Editor File :

```
import { emoji } from "@atlaskit/util-data-test";
<Editor emojiProvider={emoji.storyData.getEmojiResource()}/>
```

Note : I have noticed that dependency structure is changed in version @atlaskit/util-data-test@16.0.0

Can someone suggest how to achive this thing with the latest version of @atlaskit/util-data-test?

Answer (score 1):

Following changes worked for me:

```
import { getEmojiResource } from "@atlaskit/util-data-test/get-emoji-resource";
<Editor emojiProvider={getEmojiResource()}/>
```

Comment: Can you upvote if my solution helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

emoji is not exported from "@atlaskit/util-data-test"
look at this documentation,
https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/elements/emoji

The implementation is now different

```js
import { getEmojiRepository } from '@atlaskit/util-data-test/get-emoji-repository';
import { Emoji } from '@atlaskit/emoji/element';

const emojiService = getEmojiRepository();
const wtf = emojiService.findByShortName(':wtf:');
  const wtfEmoji = wtf ? (
    <Emoji
      emoji={wtf}
      showTooltip={true}
      fitToHeight={fitToHeight}
      selected={true}
    />
...
```